# Installing versioned packages of npm of private nexus3 repository are not available

Tags: npm, npm-install, nexus, npm-publish

I have a private repository on nexus3 configured with an npm repository. I tested publishing a library called `countdown-js@1.0.2` and it seems that everything has been published correctly.

When I try to install the package using `npm install countdown-js`, it is downloaded correctly from the repository. NPM goes to `http://localhost:5050/repository/npm-bo/countdown-js` and the following info is available:

```
{
"_id": "countdown-js",
"name": "countdown-js",
"description": "Very lightweight, no dependencies Countdown Timer that provides a simple API to get various time formats",
"dist-tags": {
"latest": "1.0.2"
},
"versions": {
"1.0.2": {
"name": "countdown-js",
```

However, when I try to install the package using `npm install countdown-js@1.0.2`, I get a 404 error. NPM goes to `http://localhost:5050/repository/npm-bo/countdown-js/1.0.2`, and the following info is available:

```
{
"success": false,
"error": "Package 'countdown-js-1.0.2' not found"
}
```

Publishing on nexus2 works fine, so does anyone know why the symbolic link with the version is not created in nexus3?

Thanks.